# Как сделать так чтобы бот реагировал на слово 'инфа' в любом предложении и выдавал ответ, например: Я:инфа какова шанс что я лысый бот: шанс равен %

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
if message.text==('инфа'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"шанс равен:{random.randint(0,100)}%")
```

Comment: if 'инфа' in message.text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if 'инфа' in message.text:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"шанс равен:{random.randint(0,100)}%")
```